# Disable slider keyboard events

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this slider in my XAML:

```
<Slider Width="250" 
        Margin="0,-2,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Name="TimeSlider"
        Maximum="100"
        Thumb.DragStarted="MouseEnterSlider"
        Thumb.DragCompleted="MouseLeaveSlider"
        ValueChanged="TimeSlider_ValueChanged" />
```

I noticed the if I press the up/down arrow keys on the keyboard, the slider will change its value.

I tried to disable it with:

```
TimeSlider.IsEnabled = false;
```

But this disables the slider completely. Is there a way to **only** disable the up/down arrow keys?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set **Focusable** to false, like so:

```
<Slider Width="250" Margin="0,-2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="TimeSlider" Maximum="100" Thumb.DragStarted="MouseEnterSlider" Thumb.DragCompleted="MouseLeaveSlider" ValueChanged="TimeSlider_ValueChanged" Focusable="False" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the PreviewKeyDown event on the Control you want to use, and handle it the way you want to handle, and set e.Handled to True, so it won't get to the slider.